# jQuery Dynamic checking for radio buttons not working, hardcoded works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing this weird issue with javascript / jquery

my code snippet is something like following

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="item_3010258" id="item_sone_3010258" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="item_3010258" id="item_stwo_3010258" value="0" />
```

jQuery / Javascript:

```
if(data[i].status === 1){
    $('#item_sone_'+data[i].id).prop("checked", true);
    console.log('#item_sone_'+data[i].id); //debug
} else if(data[i].status === 0){
    $('#item_stwo_'+data[i].id).prop("checked", true);
    console.log('#item_stwo_'+data[i].id); //debug
}
```

Above radios are dynamically generated.
Code works perfectly on my machine, though it doesn't work on some machines with same response and data.

Hardcoding following line or executing in console works.

```
$('#item_stwo_3010258').prop("checked", true);
```

I have tried logging ID in console if they are correct from //debug comment. It works executing it manually from console.

Issue is replicating on specific machines, unfortunately used by testers. Machines have same browser version as mine (Chrome / Safari browser).

Code doesn't work on testing machine with ANY browser while works on mine with ANY browser.

Comment: Are you sure that you pass integer type in data[i].status?

 Can you try using == instead of === ?
Another option is that you are accessing the radios before they are appended to the DOM

Comment: Yes it is strict integer, checked! Tried using == and nothing else is interacting with radios, it only loads from single function.

Comment: Where are you setting `data`? I feel that the issue may be in the surrounding context, rather than the code you've included in your question.

Comment: Data is valid `console.log('#item_stwo_'+data[i].id);` this logs `'#item_stwo_3010258'` This exactly is bugging me, no errors or warnings in console.